# Как сделать функцию для подгрузки соответствующего видео?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, click

Привет!

Есть на странице 20 блоков или больше в дальнейшем будет

```
<div class="watch-video">...</div>
```

на сайте есть отдельно загружен файл videos.html
в нем iframe-ы с ютюба, типа:

```
<div id="video_1"><div class="overlay"></div><div class="popup"><div class="close-popup"></div>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/avNIsHdwtOg?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0?ecver=1&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div>
<div id="video_2"><div class="overlay"></div><div class="popup"><div class="close-popup"></div>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/e_BeZ0uxcAo?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0?ecver=1&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div>
```

При клике на `.watch-video` я подгружаю на страницу видео в `div`

```
$(document).on('click', '.watch-video', function(){
$('#uploadVideos').load('videos.html #video_1');});
```

Не могу понять как сделать чтобы при клике, допустим, на первый `div.watch-video` с файла videos.html подгружался первый по счету `div` c видео на страницу, при клике на второй - подряжался второй и так далее?
Чтобы самому не писать постоянно

```
$('.watch-video').eq(0).click(function(){
$('#uploadVideos').load('videos.html #video_1);.....
```

и так далее, а автоматизировать это всё, так скажем.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен!

Если кому-то пригодиться, то...

*Помогли на тостере*

добавить блокам `.watch-video` порядковый номер через атрибут, например **data-index="1"**

```
$('.watch-video').click(function() {
const index = $(this).attr('data-index');
$('#uploadVideos').load('videos.html #video_'+index);
```